# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. error

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

My ajax call is as follows

```
var data = {};
                    data.name = name;
                    data.phone = phone;
                    data.address=address;

$.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'http://localhost:5000/endpoint',                      
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });
```

and I am using node-js express server

and my server code is

```
app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res){
    var obj = {};
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(5000);
```

I have tried the other solutions posted but I still keep getting this error

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:3000` is therefore not allowed access.

What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your routing on your server, add :

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});
```

You can replace the ***** with the URL of authorized domains.

**More informations :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS